# General purpose open source taxonomy database

Tags: database, language-agnostic, open-source, dictionary, taxonomy

I am looking for a database which could help me group thousands of English-language keywords to few general disciplines.

For example:

`I HAVE THIS => I WANT TO HAVE THIS

cat => animal

chair => household

wine => drink

deer => animal

beer => drink

glass => household, drink

total 50 000 keywords => total <100 disciplines`

I guess that organizing keywords into disciplines can be very tricky. I don't really care about what will be the disciplines. I only want to have my 50 000 keywords grouped into less than 100 disciplines.

Do you know a dictionary database that can do that?

Comment: One of the flags should be AI or knowledge base or expert systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of associating the keywords with dictionary entries:

- One general method of getting what you need would be to look at this as a multi-class classification problem:
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification
- One implementation that I believe should work for your particular need would be SVM Light:
  http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_struct.html
- You will still need to train the classifier with sample data, of course, so you will need to have a representative training set.

In terms of actually organizing the results in a database, it seems relatively simple:

- create a dictionary table (with the < 100 terms)
- create a keyword table, with foreign keys to the dictionary table
- the natural (logical) primary key of the keyword table would be (keyword, dictionary_table_id)

Answer (score 1):

WordNet would be a good solution for this problem:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet
- http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Example:

- [hypernyms of dog](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=dog&i=4&h=100000000000#c)